# Use R forecast::arfima to forecast anti-persistent series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arfima

I'm trying to use the R forecast package to forecast an anti-persistent time-series (assumed to be an ARFIMA(0, d, 0) series, with d somewhat negative, e.g. d = -0.25).  The forecast::arfima function limits d to be in the range (0, 0.5).  I'm curious whether it's possible to
a) transform the series to be long-memory (using e.g. diff(series, -0.5)).
b) forecast the transformed series.
c) transform the transformed series + forecast back from long-memory to anti-persistent.

E.g., expressed as a R function:

## #

### Forecast an anti-persistent series, aka one that

### is fractionally integrated with d in range -0.5 to 0.

## #

lmuForecastAntiPersistentSeries = function(series.V,
                                           n.periods,
                                           drange=c(-0.5, 0),
                       max.p=0,
                       max.q=0,
                       ...) {
  # Fractionally integrate series by 0.5 - should transform series
  # so that it is long-memory, rather than anti-persistent.
  series.dm50.V = diffseries(series.V, -0.5);
  arfima.model = arfima(series.dm50.V, drange=drange+0.5,
                        max.p=max.p, max.q=max.q, ...);

# Extract de-noised version of long-memory series.
  fitted.V = fitted(arfima.model);

# Forecast series, also in long-memory space.
  forecast.V = forecast(arfima.model, n.periods)[[2]];

# Transform back to being anti-peristent series.
  total.series.V = c(series.dm50.V, forecast.V);
  ret.V = diffseries(total.series.V, 0.5);

# Strip off 1st part of series, so that were only
  # left with the forecast.
  return(ret.V[-(1:length(series.V))]);
}

Does anyone have any good intuition for whether this approach works - and even better, if not, what's wrong with it?

Thank You
-mc

Comment: Unfortunately not - that post was just me re-posting this original with some nicer formatting to make the example R code easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write the comment above. It was automatically generated by the system on a close vote.